# How to uninstall a downloaded application from Ubuntu system?

Tags: uninstall

I have downloaded an application on Ubuntu call EducationSuite Gcompris. I want to unistall it. How do I do that?

Comment: How have you installed it? Search in `Software Center` for "Gcompris".

Answer (score 0):

Open up Ubuntu Software Center, in the search field type in "gcompris" and your package should show in the results. Click this entry and hit the "Uninstall" button.

Another method is to try opening a terminal and type in `sudo apt-get remove --purge gcompris` followed by a `sudo apt-get autoremove` to get rid of all remaining files that should be around. This should fully remove gcompris from your system.